# Is there any way(s) to minimize and maximize GUI and its content made in QT Designer and PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, qt-designer, minimize, maximize

I'm doing a project using PyCharm and QT Designer as tool for designing and building graphical user interfaces (GUIs), upon clicking the maximize and minimize button/tab in the upper right of the GUI, the window will maximize and minimize but the content, the forms itself in the GUI will be the same, I tried adjusting the sizePolicy in QT Designer to expanding but it doesn't work.
Is there any way(s) to maximize and minimize its content(s)?

```
 def restoreOrMaximizeWindow(self):  # Restore or maximize your window
    # Global windows state
    global WINDOW_SIZE  # The default value is zero to show that the size is not maximized
    win_status = WINDOW_SIZE
    if win_status == 1:  # If the window is not maximized
        WINDOW_SIZE = 0  # Update value to show that the window has been maxmized
        self.showMaximized()
    else:
        # If the window is on its default size
        WINDOW_SIZE = 0  # Update value to show that the window has been minimized/set to normal size (which is 800 by 400)
        self.showNormal()  # Update button icon when window is minimized
```

Comment: yes it is possible but I can't tell you how because I was using QT Designer few years ago. I don't know if you don't have to use some of `layout managers` for this. And you may need special widgets which use all free space - ie. to move other widgets to the right. Probably it would be simpler check in some video tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: oh I see, thanks @furas